# Adding a checkbox field to a (custom) taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, options

I've searched and found many variations on adding custom meta to taxonomies - often its just for text fields and often to store a whole array of options.

One thing I haven't found is a way to register one checkbox on a custom taxonomy page. I've tried some more complex code that could save the checked box but wouldn't notice if it was unchecked - so I simplified the code to the basics and it still doesn't work.

Here is my code so far..

```
// A callback function to add a custom field to our "menu_page" taxonomy
function menupage_taxonomy_custom_fields() {

$altprice = get_option( 'mschema_altprice' );

?>

<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top">
    <label for="altprice_checkbox"><?php _e('Takeaway/Discount          Pricing?'); ?></label>
</th>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="altprice_checkbox" name="mschema_altprice"         value="1" <?php checked( 1, $altprice, false )?>/>

    <span class="description"><?php _e('Takeaway/Discount Pricing?');   ?></span>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}

// A callback function to save our extra taxonomy field(s)
function save_taxonomy_custom_fields( ) {  


        $ap = ( isset( $_POST['mschema_altprice'] ) &&    $_POST['mschema_altprice'] ) ? 1 : 0 ;


    update_option( 'mschema_altprice', $ap );  

}  
// Add the fields to the "presenters" taxonomy, using our callback  function
add_action( 'menu_pages_edit_form_fields', 'menupage_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );

// Save the changes made on the "presenters" taxonomy, using our callback  function
add_action( 'edited_menu_pages', 'save_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately this guy has written a great taxonomy class to solve all of this :)
https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/